# dirコマンドで取り出したファイル名を連結させたい

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

コマンドプロンプトを使用して、ファイル名を取り出し、空白で区切った一覧として出力させたいです。
バッチファイルでdirコマンドを使用した時に以下の結果になるようなときに

```
>dir /B
A.txt
B.txt
C.txt
```

以下のスクリプトでスペース区切りのファイル名が出現する想定でした。

```
@echo off  
for /F %%A in ('dir /B') do (  
    set STR=%STR% %%A  
)  
echo "%STR%"
```

想定する実行結果：

```
" A.txt B.txt C.txt"
```

しかし、上記スクリプトでは何も表示されません。
スクリプトファイルが間違ってると思われるのですが、どこを間違っているのかが、わからないためご教示いただければと思います。

Answer (score 5):

そのままの例がSETコマンドのヘルプ(`set /?`)に書いてありました。

まず、遅延環境変数の展開をONにしておく(`cmd /V:ON`)
そうすると以下の様に書けます。

```
@echo off
set STR=
for /F %%A in ('dir /B') do set STR=!STR! %%A
echo "%STR%"
```

また、FORの部分は単に`for %%A in (*) do set STR=!STR! %%A` で良いと思います。

でも、このために`cmd /V:ON`をするとコマンドシェルをネストしてしまいますし、
JScript または、VBScriptを使用するのがいいのではないかと思います。

Comment: BAT内部では`SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`を実行することで遅延環境変数の展開を有効化できます。

Comment: はい、他の方の回答を見ましたので・

Answer (score 4):

私の環境（Windows7）では、結果は`" c.txt"`になりました。

お望みの結果を得るには、遅延環境変数を使います。

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set STR=
for /F %%A in ('dir /B') do (
  set STR=!STR! %%A
)
echo "%STR%"
endlocal
```

詳しいことは、以下のページが参考になると思います。

[バッチファイル。IF文やFOR文の中で複数コマンドを書く時の注意点 - Windowsのコマンドプロンプト(bat,cmd) - to_dk notebook](http://tounderlinedk.blogspot.jp/2011/01/if-windowsbatcmd.html)

Answer (score 4):

既に遅延評価の回答がありますが、サブルーチンを使う方法もあります。この場合は、`cmd.exe` に `/V` オプションを付けなくても期待通りの結果を得ることができます。

```
@echo off
set STR=
for /F %%A in ('dir /B') do (
  call :add %%A
)
echo "%STR%"

:add
set STR=%STR% %1
```